# What's a organized or standarized way of testing PHP code using var_dump and print_r?

Tags: php

I usually, test code with PHP code, special PHP variables with `var_dump` and `print_r`
But I always end up placing them everywhere and messing up the code.

Is it common to include them or place them in an organised way?

Comment: I use them too. But why don't you just remove them after use?

Comment: To perform tests you definitely have to get a look at some testing framework, such as phpunit

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a debugger? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011008/debugging-php-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap every `var_dump` or `print_r` in this way:

```
if($debug) {
    var_dump($foo);
}
```

Then you can set `$debug = true` at the top of every file - or even better, in a file that is included by every other file, so that you can globally turn debugging on or off. You can also programatically set the debug flag like this:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "localhost") {
    $debug = true;
} else {
    $debug = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not! You shouldn't rely on var_dump and print_r for testing and debugging. Instead start writing unit tests and start using a debugger!

What you need, in order to write quality PHP code, is an IDE like PhpStorm, Aptana, Eclipse, Zend Studio or NetBeans which provide you with an easy way to integrated debugging and unit testing.

There are two good debuggers for PHP, Zend Debugger and Xdebug.
There is one de facto standard for writing unit tests for PHP, phpUnit.

Use var_dump and print_r only occasionally and never leave them in the code! I strongly disagree with Sam Starlings method. I think it inhibits the development of best practices.

I would also advice using some sort of 'ENVIRONMENT' constant for defining the environment instead of the localhost/IP approach.

Comment: Let me note that I agree with you, despite the answer I posted. PHP is a language that is often used for small personal projects, as well as serious systems. In the former case, people can print_r to their heart's content. For anyone who considers themselves more than a hobbyist, a more powerful solution is required.

Answer (score 0):

Sam's solution is useful, and probably sufficient for many very small projects, but it does involve adding a lot of superfluous code to application logic. In a similar case I would define something like

```
function aray_out($arr, $continue = NULL) { 
  echo '<pre>';
  (is_array($arr)) ? print_r($arr) : var_dump($arr);
  echo '</pre>';
  if(!$continue)
    exit();
}
```

When something isn't working as expected, we can just bash out `array_out($_SESSION)` (or whatever), save and retry, removing the line once we're confident our variables are holding the right stuff. Wrapping the output in `<pre>` tags makes it a lot more readable.

We could also `require_once 'debug.php'` in our malfunctioning scripts, using that file to dump our environment.

```
# debug.php

$your_ip = '192.168.0.1';

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $your_ip || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') {

  array_out($_SERVER, 1);
  array_out($_SESSION, 1);
  array_out($_POST, 1);

  # etc.

}
```

This has the added benefit of giving **us** information, as we have set the IP address we are accessing the server from, but leaving output for other users the same.

Of course, **more serious use cases need more serious tools.**